# External referenced DTD in XML

Tags: xml, dtd, xml-validation

test.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE email SYSTEM "test.dtd">
<email>
<von>test@test.com</von>
<zu>xxx@example.com</zu>
<titel>Hello</titel>
<text>Dear John....;-).</text>
<prior type="schnell"/>
</email>
```

test.dtd:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE email [
<!ELEMENT email (von,zu,titel,text,prior)>
<!ELEMENT von (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT zu (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT titel (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT text (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST prior type CDATA #REQUIRED >
]>
```

Error Code in test.dtd

> The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed. [2]

Please help!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have duplicate DOCTYPE declarations. If you want to reference an external DTD:

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE email SYSTEM "test.dtd">
<email>
<von>test@test.com</von>
<zu>xxx@example.com</zu>
<titel>Hello</titel>
<text>Dear John....;-).</text>
<prior type="schnell"/>
</email>
```

**test.dtd**

```
<!ELEMENT email (von,zu,titel,text,prior)>
<!ELEMENT von (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT zu (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT titel (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT text (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT prior EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST prior type CDATA #REQUIRED >
```

If you want your DTD as part of the XML file (internal subset):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE email [
<!ELEMENT email (von,zu,titel,text,prior)>
<!ELEMENT von (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT zu (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT titel (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT text (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT prior EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST prior type CDATA #REQUIRED >
]>
<email>
<von>test@test.com</von>
<zu>xxx@example.com</zu>
<titel>Hello</titel>
<text>Dear John....;-).</text>
<prior type="schnell"/>
</email>
```

**NOTE: You're also missing an ELEMENT declaration for your `prior` element.**