# Having Trouble Implementing A External DTD

Tags: xml, external, dtd

**EDIT**

I am having trouble implementing a DTD. I keep getting an error in my DTD saying:

"The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed."

In my XML document I get the error:

"The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed."

DTD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- New document created with EditiX at Sun Jul 06 07:25:48 AST 2014 -->


<!ELEMENT periodic-elements (periodic-element*)>
<!ELEMENT periodic-element (symbol, name, atomic-number, atomic_weight)>
<!ELEMENT symbol (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT atomic_number (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT atomic_weight (#PCDATA)>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- New document created with EditiX at Sun Jul 06 07:25:48 AST 2014 -->

<!DOCTYPE periodic SYSTEM "C:\Users\Randy\Desktop\CMIS 170\Week 3\Homework 3\Homework3DTD.txt">
<periodic>
<element>  
  <symbol>FE</symbol> 
  <name>Iron</name> 
  <atomic_number>26</atomic_number>
  <atomic_weight>55.845</atomic_weight> 
</element>

<element>
  <symbol>Ir</symbol> 
  <name>Iridium</name> 
  <atomic_number>77</atomic_number>
  <atomic_weight>192.217</atomic_weight> 
</element>

<element>  
  <symbol>P</symbol> 
  <name>Phosphorus</name> 
  <atomic_number>15</atomic_number>
  <atomic_weight>30.973762</atomic_weight> 
</element>

<element>  
  <symbol>Uut</symbol> 
  <name>Ununtrium</name> 
  <atomic_number>113</atomic_number>
  <atomic_weight>284</atomic_weight> 
</element>

<element>  
  <symbol>Po</symbol> 
  <name>Polonium</name> 
  <atomic_number>84</atomic_number>
  <atomic_weight>209</atomic_weight> 
</element>
</periodic>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with external referenced DTD in XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455394/problem-with-external-referenced-dtd-in-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the DOCTYPE declaration from your DTD.

See [External referenced DTD in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455394/problem-with-external-referenced-dtd-in-xml/5455469#5455469) for a better explanation.

You also need to change `elements` to `periodic` in the DOCTYPE declaration in your XML. The name in the DOCTYPE declaration must match the name of the root element.

**Edit**

The names in your DTD and your XML don't all match. For example, in your DTD you have `periodic-elements` and `periodic-element`, but your XML has `periodic` and `element`.

Also, your declaration for `periodic-element` references the element `atomic-number`, but your declaration is `atomic_number`.

Here's a version that validates. You should be able to start with this and modify it however you like.

**DTD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- New document created with EditiX at Sun Jul 06 07:25:48 AST 2014 -->


<!ELEMENT periodic-elements (periodic-element*)>
<!ELEMENT periodic-element (symbol, name, atomic_number, atomic_weight)>
<!ELEMENT symbol (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT atomic_number (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT atomic_weight (#PCDATA)>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- New document created with EditiX at Sun Jul 06 07:25:48 AST 2014 -->

<!DOCTYPE periodic-elements SYSTEM "C:\Users\Randy\Desktop\CMIS 170\Week 3\Homework 3\Homework3DTD.txt">
<periodic-elements>
    <periodic-element>  
        <symbol>FE</symbol> 
        <name>Iron</name> 
        <atomic_number>26</atomic_number>
        <atomic_weight>55.845</atomic_weight> 
    </periodic-element>

    <periodic-element>
        <symbol>Ir</symbol> 
        <name>Iridium</name> 
        <atomic_number>77</atomic_number>
        <atomic_weight>192.217</atomic_weight> 
    </periodic-element>

    <periodic-element>  
        <symbol>P</symbol> 
        <name>Phosphorus</name> 
        <atomic_number>15</atomic_number>
        <atomic_weight>30.973762</atomic_weight> 
    </periodic-element>

    <periodic-element>  
        <symbol>Uut</symbol> 
        <name>Ununtrium</name> 
        <atomic_number>113</atomic_number>
        <atomic_weight>284</atomic_weight> 
    </periodic-element>

    <periodic-element>  
        <symbol>Po</symbol> 
        <name>Polonium</name> 
        <atomic_number>84</atomic_number>
        <atomic_weight>209</atomic_weight> 
    </periodic-element>
</periodic-elements>
```

Comment: Ok I edited this post with what you told me to change and I still get errors. I put the errors within my edit.