# The root element must be well-formed

Tags: xml, dtd

I have been having trouble with this assignment for weeks now. Everytime I change something to fix a problem, another problem pops up. Any help would be appreciated. In my DTD document I get the error:

The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.

In my XML document I get:

An element type is required in the declaration of element type "viewer_rating".

However, I believe both errors are coming from my DTD document. Any help would be appreciated.

DTD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- New document created with EditiX at Sun Jul 06 07:25:48 AST 2014 -->

<!ELEMENT movies (movie*)>  
<!ELEMENT movie (title, genre, movie_rating, viewer_rating, summary, year, director+, runtime, studio, actors+)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT genre (#PCDATA|action|comedy|drama|family|foreign|horror|musical|other)*>
<!ELEMENT  movie_rating (#PCDATA|G|PG|PG-13|R|NC-17)*>
<!ELEMENT  viewer_rating (#PCDATA|0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5)*>
<!ELEMENT summary (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT director (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT runtime (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT studio (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT actors (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST actors id CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- New document created with EditiX at Sun Jul 13 10:41:29 AST 2014 -->

<!DOCTYPE movies SYSTEM "MoviesDTD.dtd">


<movies>
<movie>   
<title>Transcendence</title>  
<genre>Action</genre>  
<movie_rating>PG-13</movie_rating>  
<viewer_rating>4</viewer_rating>  
<summary>In Transcendence, Dr. Will Carter is an expert in Artificial Intelligence, and initially is excited by the promises it offers the world at large. Unfortunately, when he is diagnosed with a terminal disease, his motives change and he becomes focused on his own transcendence. Now he is racing against his own mortality as extremists attempt to stop him. Max Waters is his best friend and a researcher as well, and is torn between helping his friend and what that will mean for society at large.</summary>  
<year>2014</year>  
<director>Wall Pfistery</director>  
<runtime>119</runtime>  
<studio>Warner Bros.</studio>
<actors id="1000">Johnny Depp</actors>
<actors id="1001">Paul Bettany</actors>
<actors id="1002">Rebecca Hall</actors>  
</movie>
</movies>
```

Thanks again in advance for any help.

Comment: Try removing the `<!-- New document created with EditiX at Sun Jul 13 10:41:29 AST 2014 -->` comment at the top.

Comment: I made a new DTD type and copy and pasted my code over but I am still getting a: An element type is required in the declaration of element type "viewer_rating".

Comment: I suggest putting only one <movie> in this XML just to reduce the amount of code people need to look at and narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comment in [Attribute is required and must be specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079911/attribute-is-required-and-must-be-specified/25084622#25084622)...

> The error "*An element type is required in the declaration of element type "viewer_rating".*" is because of the numbers in (#PCDATA|0|1|2|3|4|5)*. You're trying to specify atomic values when only element names are allowed. Since an element name can't start with a number, you get the error. You should go back to using attributes for those like I mentioned in my answer.

Here's an example of what I was talking about using your example above. (Both the XML and the DTD have been modified.)

Also, you were trying to mix #PCDATA (CDATA in an attribute) with enumerated values. This isn't possible. It also looks like you were trying to allow multiple enumerated values; this also won't work. If you need multiple values, like for multiple `genre` values, you may need to remove the enumeration and use CDATA instead.

**DTD**

```
<!ELEMENT movies (movie*)>  
<!ELEMENT movie (title, summary, year, director+, runtime, studio, actors+)>
<!ATTLIST movie
            genre (action|comedy|drama|family|foreign|horror|musical|other) #IMPLIED
            movie_rating (G|PG|PG-13|R|NC-17) #IMPLIED
            viewer_rating (0|1|2|3|4|5) #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT summary (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT director (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT runtime (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT studio (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT actors (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST actors id CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

**XML**

```
<!DOCTYPE movies SYSTEM "MoviesDTD.dtd">
<movies>
    <movie genre="action" movie_rating="PG-13" viewer_rating="4">
        <title>Transcendence</title>  
        <summary>In Transcendence, Dr. Will Carter is an expert in Artificial Intelligence, and initially is excited by the promises it offers the world at large. Unfortunately, when he is diagnosed with a terminal disease, his motives change and he becomes focused on his own transcendence. Now he is racing against his own mortality as extremists attempt to stop him. Max Waters is his best friend and a researcher as well, and is torn between helping his friend and what that will mean for society at large.</summary>  
        <year>2014</year>  
        <director>Wall Pfistery</director>  
        <runtime>119</runtime>  
        <studio>Warner Bros.</studio>
        <actors id="1000">Johnny Depp</actors>
        <actors id="1001">Paul Bettany</actors>
        <actors id="1002">Rebecca Hall</actors>  
    </movie>
</movies>
```

Comment: Thank you so much it validates and works great. You saved me so much stress. I have like 3 days left till its due.

Comment: @randygilman - you're welcome. If there is anything that you don't understand about the answer, don't hesitate to ask. :-)