# Interpreting DTD from specifications

Tags: xml, dtd

I am given the following specifications:

• there is one root element called products

• the products element contains a sequence of product sub elements, one for each product in the database

• each product element contains one name, one price, and one description subelement, and a sequence of store
subelements, one for each store that sells that product:

• each store element contains one name, one phone, and one markup .

So far I have come up with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE exercise 3 [
<!ELEMENT products (pid, name, price, description, stores)>
<!ELEMENT pid (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT stores (store_name, phone, markup)>
<!ELEMENT store_name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT phone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT markup (#PCDATA)>
```

Do you think this DTD matches the specifications?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You do it exactly the way you've done it with products, with a different set of names for the elements.

Comment: If I include the store elements do I need to have unique names because currently they share sub element names with products?

Comment: Why can't you try yourself and see if it works with the same names or not? If you had, you'd be done by now. It's supposed to be *your* exercise, not ours.

Answer (score 0):

A couple comments on your DTD:

1. In the doctype declaration `<!DOCTYPE exercise 3 [` the name should be the same as the root element so instead of `exercise 3` it should be `products`. However, you shouldn't need the doctype if this DTD is an external file. You would want to use it if your DTD and XML are combined. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5455469/317052 for more details.
2. Element names don't need to be unique, so you can have a single `name` element that can be used in both `product` and `store`.

Here's what I'd do based on the specification...

> • there is one root element called products
>
> • the products element contains a sequence of product sub elements,
>   one for each product in the database

```
<!ELEMENT products (product*)>
```

> • each product element contains one name, one price, and one
>   description subelement, and a sequence of store subelements, one for
>   each store that sells that product:

```
<!ELEMENT product (name, price, description, store*)>
```

> • each store element contains one name, one phone, and one markup .

```
<!ELEMENT store (name, phone, markup)>
```

Here's the complete DTD with spaces added for readability...

```
<!ELEMENT products      (product*)                         >
<!ELEMENT product       (name, price, description, store*) >
<!ELEMENT store         (name, phone, markup)              >
<!ELEMENT name          (#PCDATA)                          >
<!ELEMENT price         (#PCDATA)                          >
<!ELEMENT description   (#PCDATA)                          >
<!ELEMENT phone         (#PCDATA)                          >
<!ELEMENT markup        (#PCDATA)                          >
```