# why I cannot validate my code and why I get an error message

Tags: html, xml, database, dtd

Hello I just started to learn XML and DTDs and I cannot get my code to validate. I am using notepad++ to validate my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE A [


<!ELEMENT A (B,D,F)>
<!ELEMENT B (C*)>
<!ELEMENT C (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT D (F*)>
<!ELEMENT F (#PCDATA)>

]>
```

also when I made a check XML syntax I get an error mesage in line 11 (the last one)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE A SYSTEM "d3.dtd">


<A>
    <B>
        <C></C>
        <C></C>
    </B>
    <F></F>
</A>
```

Comment: What's the error message? The problem is most likely that you have duplicate doctype declarations; one in your XML and one in your DTD. Try removing the one in your DTD (leave the element declarations though). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5455469/317052 for more info.

Comment: Also, your DTD says that `D` is required, but your XML does not have a `D` element.

Comment: the error message is "Unable to load the DTD d3.dtd"