# Why does Oxygen not accept the doctype-element of my DTD document?

Tags: validation, dtd, oxygenxml

I have written a DTD-document which will serve as a standard for xml-tagging texts in a corpus. (I am relying on using Oxygen (or similar xml-handling software) to help me fill out the attributes of each tagged element in these texts, or the task will become herculean.)
I am experiencing a problem which seems to be connected to the the !DOCTYPE-element itself.
I get the following error message when I try to validate my xml documents against the DTD:

> "The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type
> declaration must be well-formed."

The declaration elements in the meat of the DTD do not seem to be the problem; I have proofread them several times now, and without the enclosing "<!DOCTYPE []>"-tag, Oxygen has no issue with them. In addition, Oxygen underlines the initial characters "<!DOC>" in the second line ("<!DOCTYPE [...]"), and marks out the closing "]>" in red, again indicating that the "<!DOCTYPE []>" bit of the code is where the trouble is.

To test whether the problem really was the !DOCTYPE-element, I made a second, very minimal, DTD-file in Oxygen. That file threw the same error. It looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE test [
<!ELEMENT test (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT vest (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

I am fairly inexperienced with xml and with Oxygen, and I cannot for the life of me tell what the error is here. If anyone has a suggestion for a solution, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ugh! I just realised I could check what Oxygen's sample .dtd looks like - and it seems the answer is... there is no !DOCTYPE-declaration in an external DTD?
(I will check this out in the office tomorrow. Until then - I feel kind of silly if it was this easy...)

Comment: Correct. The doctype declaration should not be included in an [external subset](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-extSubset) (the technical term for an external DTD). Take a look at https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd for more info.

Comment: Related/duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455394/external-referenced-dtd-in-xml